# Import React Component without Webpack

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a simple web profile using React and am trying separate the Navbar class into separate file.

I would like to have:

navbar.js

```
//Navbar Component
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const home = React.createElement('button', {className: 'button1'}, 'Home');
    const contact = React.createElement('button', {className: 'button2'}, 'Contact');

    return React.createElement('div', null, home, contact);
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Along with:

index.js

```
import Navbar from './navbar.js'

// Creates and renders all individual components
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(Navbar, null, null);
  }
}

// Finalize - Render App which then renders all components
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

It only seems to work when both classes are deeclared in same file as follows:

```
//Navbar Component
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const home = React.createElement('button', {className: 'button1'}, 'Home');
    const contact = React.createElement('button', {className: 'button2'}, 'Contact');

    return React.createElement('div', null, home, contact);
  }
}

// Creates and renders all individual components
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(Navbar, null, null);
  }
}

// Finalize - Render App which then renders all components
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any tips on importing this component?

Comment: Did you try using require('./navbar.js')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is to add the attribute `type="module"` to your `<script>` tag in the `index.html` file, like below:

```
<script src="path/to/your/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

Then, browsers will interpret your inline `index.js` code as an ECMAScript module and your import statement should work. More info can be found [here](https://v8.dev/features/modules) (just search for type="module").

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I saw this approach but I could not get it to work first time around. I tried again and now it works - THANK YOU!!